# angular2 dependency injection error

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

i am trying to access a simple method from a service class in a component.

```
//myfriend.service.ts

export class MyFriendService(){

constructor(){}

testMe() {
    window.alert("im friend service");
}
}


//myfriend.component.ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyFriendService} from 'app/components/myfriend/myfriend.service';

@Component({
directives: [],
providers: [MyFriendService],
templateUrl: `app/components/myfriend/myfriend-view.html`
})

export class MyFriendCmp {

constructor(myFriendService: MyFriendService) {

    myFriendService.testMe();

}

}
```

it is throwing an error

```
myFriendService.testMe is not a function.
```

I spent a lot of time in this to get this work.but still trying.Help me to figure this out. Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/x9O4VPwXRQWdZQFixzJu?p=preview)

Oh can you believe this? It took very long to figure it out. But you have put

**not required parenthesis** look at this line 
**export class MyFriendService()**  <=This parenthesis not required.

I have made two to three plunkr and every time it was working then took lot of time to figure this out that you have made problem with parenthesis.

```
export class MyFriendService{

constructor(){}

    testMe() {
         window.alert("im friend service");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to bring this in plunkr and will give you the link. What you mean by outside. I have imported it anyway.

Comment: @micronyks nice eyes +1..even I took 10 mins with plunkr & left it.. :D

Comment: It took so long @Pankaj. I was like everything is fine then what's the problem. Then line by line I compared everything and found out the problem. Then I updated answer but  then lately came to know that around 22 mins ago Nishanthd solved it. hahahaha...

Comment: @micronyks great.Cheers now. :)